# How to get assignment Id from URL when ExternalQuestion of mturk is used

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am using the `ExternalQuestion` of Amazon Mechanical Turk. I have created an iframe in my project. My aspx page is accepting URLs.

I give list of URLs in a batch to my project.

Each URL becomes a HIT. So basically I am passing a URL to my aspx page. I also want the AssignmentId of that batch. How do I get that?

My iframe `src` is: `src="https://NameofmyServer/Pagename.aspx?url=${url}"`

I also want AssignemntId to be passed with this HIT. How do I do that?